# How do you retrieve the estimation sample in R?

Tags: r, regression

**Update:** The fixest package now includes a function `obs()` that retrieves the indices of the observations used in a regression.

**Original post:** I would like to obtain the estimation sample from a model object, i.e. the observations that were not dropped due to missing values. This seems to be simple for standard `lm` regressions (using `case.names()`) but less so for more recent packages such as `fixest`.

Is there any general way to access the estimation sample, irrespective of the package used for estimation?

My attempts for both `lm` and `fixest` objects are:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(insight)
library(fixest)

# create data with NA -----------------------------------------------------

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>% 
  mutate(cyl = na_if(cyl, 4))


# lm ----------------------------------------------------------------------

mod_lm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * disp, data = dat)
obs <- as.integer(case.names(mod_lm))

dat %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% obs)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 12
#>    model         mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Mazda RX4    21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2 Mazda RX4 …  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3 Hornet 4 D…  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  4 Hornet Spo…  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  5 Valiant      18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  6 Duster 360   14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  7 Merc 280     19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#>  8 Merc 280C    17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
#>  9 Merc 450SE   16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
#> 10 Merc 450SL   17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
#> # … with 11 more rows


# fixest ------------------------------------------------------------------

mod_fe <- fixest::feols(mpg ~ cyl * disp, data = dat)
#> NOTE: 11 observations removed because of NA values (RHS: 11).

# does not work
case.names(mod_fe)
#> NULL

# remove missing values manually for all variables used in the regression
vars <- find_predictors(mod_fe, flatten = TRUE)

dat %>% 
  filter(if_all(
    all_of(vars),
    ~ !is.na(.x)
  ))
#> # A tibble: 21 x 12
#>    model         mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Mazda RX4    21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2 Mazda RX4 …  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3 Hornet 4 D…  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  4 Hornet Spo…  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  5 Valiant      18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  6 Duster 360   14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  7 Merc 280     19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#>  8 Merc 280C    17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
#>  9 Merc 450SE   16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
#> 10 Merc 450SL   17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
#> # … with 11 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic function `case.names` has no method written for objects of class `"fixest"`. The solution is to look at `str(mod_fe)` and write your own method.

```
case.names.fixest <- function(object, ...){
  no <- object$obsRemoved
  seq_len(object$nobs_origin)[-no]
}

case.names(mod_fe)
# [1]  1  2  4  5  6  7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 22 23 24 25 29 30 31
```

Comment: So in other words there could not possibly be a function that extracts the estimation sample irrespective of the model class because each object class could be structured arbitrarily. And to make a generic such as case.names work for a given model class, I'd either have to define it in my own environment or ask the developer of the class to include the method in his package?

Comment: @dufei Yes, that's about it. `case.names` is in base package `stats` and the R Core Team cannot guess how each package developer will structure their modeling functions' return values. It's up to them to write methods. If you contact `maintainer("fixest")` you (and all others) might get it in the next package version.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specifically for the *fixest* package. using *mod_fe$fixef_id* can extract the estimation sample. However, the identifier are saved as attribution. To extract them, save `attr(mod_fe$fixef_id,"fixef_names")` as a stand-alone variable. The developers probably have added this feature.

Comment: No.  As @RuiBarradas states explicitly, the accepted answer creates a function to provide the requested information.  The function is *not* part of the `fixest` package.